# From Matlab to C#

Tags: c#, matlab

I have a simple `.m` file that plots the [BER](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_error_rate) as a function of the [SNR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal-to-noise_ratio) in [BPSK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase-shift_keying#Binary_phase-shift_keying_.28BPSK.29) modulation. I want to do the same thing but in C#.

Is there a way that I can import the `.m` file to C#? Or do I have to write the code again for C#?

Answer (score 2):

Each version of Matlab has his own MCR (Matlab Compiler Runtime) you can find this in a folder of Matlab it self. Install this as step 1.

Remember when you upgrade your Matlab and rebuild your assembly the assembly won't work because it's binded to the MCR that came with the version of Matlab, it is NOT backwards/forwards compatible.

Here comes the second step. In Matlab it's possible to create assemblys of in this case your .m file. You do this with the [Matlab Builder NE](http://www.mathworks.nl/products/netbuilder/).

When you have created your assemblyes you can easily import the created files and call the functions just like you would in Matlab.

I can provide you with a couple of links to were you can find information. Unfortunately I can't give you examples of my own because I created this as a product for a internship where I don't work anymore. If I have some information I will share this with you, also if you have any further question let me know.

Links:

1. [Integrating MATLAB with C#](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/12987-integrating-matlab-with-c)
2. [MATLAB Builder NE](http://www.mathworks.nl/products/netbuilder/)

Also watch these [[examples](http://www.mathworks.nl/products/netbuilder/examples.html)].